# In Celery are there significant performance implications of using many queues

Tags: python, celery

Are there substantial performance implications that I should keep in mind when Celery workers are pulling from multiple (or perhaps many) queues? For example, would there be a significant performance penalty if my system were designed so that workers pulled from 10 to 15 queues rather than just 1 or 2? As a follow-up, what if some of those queues are sometimes empty?

Comment: I don't know from experience, but I doubt it's something to worry about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer to your question on queue limits is:

Don't worry having multiple queues will not be worse or better, broker are designed to handle huge numbers of them. Off course in a lot of use cases you don't need so many, except really advanced one. Empty queues don't create any problem, they just take a tiny amount of memory on the broker.

Don't forget also that you have other things like exchanges and bindings, also there you don't have real limits but is better you [understand](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html) the performance implication of each of them before using it (a TOPIC exchange will use more CPU than a direct one for example)

To give you a more complete answer let's look at the performance topic from a more generic point of view.

When looking at a distributed system based on message passing like Celery there are 2 main topics to analyze from the point of view of performance:

1. The workers number and concurrency factor.

   As you probably already know each celery worker has a concurrency parameter that sets how many tasks can be executed at the same time, this should be set in relation with the server capacity(CPU, RAM, I/O) and off course also based on the type of tasks that the specific consumer will execute (depends on the queue that it will consume).

   Off course depending on the total number of tasks you need to execute in a certain time window you will need to decide how many workers/servers you will need to have up and running.
2. The broker, the Single point of Failure in this architecture style.

   The broker, especially RabbitMQ, is designed to manage millions of messages without any problem, however more messages it will need to store more memory will use and more are the messages to route more CPU it will use.

   This machine should be well tuned too and if possible be in [high availability](https://www.rabbitmq.com/pacemaker.html).

   Off course the main thing to avoid is the messages are consumed at a lower rate than they are produced otherwise your queue will keep growing and your RabbitMQ will explode. Here you can find [some hints](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/09/24/sizing-your-rabbits/).

There are cases where you may also need to increase the number of tasks executed in a certain time frame but on only in response to peaks of requests. The nice thing about this architecture is that you can monitor the size of the queues and when you understand is growing to fast you could create new machines on the fly with a celery worker already configured and than turn it off when they are not needed. This is a quite cost saving and efficient approach.

One hint, remember to don't store celery tasks results in RabbitMQ.

Comment: Thanks for the comments -- very useful. Perhaps I'm misreading, but these notes focus on the performance implications for the broker (eg RabbitMQ or, in my case, Redis). I think my question mainly had in mind concerns about the performance of my Python application code and, more directly, of the Celery framework. For example, will Celery be slower in delivering tasks to my workers if they are operating across many queues rather just a couple?

Comment: Hi,that's because from celery point of view there is basically 0 impact. In fact I could hardly imagine a framework heavily based on message passing that is not well handling consuming from multiple queues being successful.